# Computer cannot boot to Ubuntu 13.04 after installing Netflix-desktop and later Wine

Tags: boot, 13.04, wine, software-installation, netflix

Can anyone help me with this issue?

**Issue:** Black screen after boot attempt from GRUB (cannot boot Ubuntu, not even in failsafe mode)
**Process to get to Issue:** On Ubuntu 13.04, I installed netflix-desktop following [this procedure](http://linuxg.net/how-to-use-netflix-on-ubuntu-13-04/); Netflix app didn't show up in Unity dash, so I uninstalled and reinstalled, still to no avail. Immediately after, I installed Wine, following [this procedure](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-wine-1-6-rc4-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint-operating-systems/). Since the Netflix app was still nowhere to be found, I uninstalled Wine and reinstalled it. Nothing... so I restarted Ubuntu, only to find out that ever since I cannot boot. I've tried several of the options in Advanced options for Ubuntu on the GRUB menu but nothing.

I have a computer with Windows 8 Pro dual-boot so I'm able to keep searching for answers online, but I can't seem to use Ubuntu anymore and will have to resign and reinstall Ubuntu somehow.

Thank you for taking time in looking at my issue.

Comment: Do you see any boot errors. Or a blank screen? I'd just boot with a live cd and check the syslog/dmesg files in my /var/log/ partition on my ubuntu to try to find out whats going on. Any relevant information from those would be very useful.

Comment: Hi Fahad Yousuf. For some reason, I did not get a notification that you posted a reply to my post (and I don't know if I'm supposed to receive updates or have to manually check if someone has replied). Anyhow, thanks for your reply and I'm letting you know that back then I decided to resolve the issue by doing a fresh OS install of Ubuntu. I didn't have much info. so I didn't mind.

Comment: Good to know you got around the issue. Enjoy.